# Can't open VSCode from command-line WSL ZSH

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vscode-remote

So I decided to quit dual-boot and start using WSL. I'm having a problem and really can figure out how to fix it.

I simply can't open VSCode using the code command from the terminal when using an external terminal. When using the integrated, a command like "code ." works just fine.

Anyone knows how to fix it? It was working good a few steps of setup ago, but I lost track and don't exactly when that happened. I'm currently using HyperJS as terminal and my integrated terminal is already running zsh and it works when the VSCode is connected to WSL and when it isn't aswell.

Anyway, hoping for a fix, 'cause I'm really lost.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fixed and it was an easy fix, but it took long for me to realize that all I had to do was one step.

**Here's the thing:** the command "code" on the integrated terminal was working like a charm because the VSCode itself was running as administrator on Windows.

My Hyper wasn't running as administrator, so all I did was:

- Right-click on HyperJS icon and go to the properties of the application
- Switch to "Compatibility" tab
- Check the "Run as administrator"

It's working without a problem now. Took me a while to realize that, but it's all good now.